# Session helper not found in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use CakePHP's session helper, like this inside a controller:

```
$this->Session->write('cart', $cart);
```

But it does not work. I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function write() on a non-object in ...
```

It's enabled in the config file, I added the session helper to the controller and the app controller

Answer (score 10):

Turns out, you also need to add `Session` as a component, so AppController looks like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $layout = 'website';

public $components = array(
    'Paginator',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session'
);

public $helpers = array(
    'Html',
    'Js' => array('Jquery'),
    'Session'
);

}
```